# Kotlin issue while sum 2 variables

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin

```
 val btnAdd = findViewById<Button>(R.id.btnAdd)
        val btnSub = findViewById<Button>(R.id.btnSub)
        btnAdd.setOnClickListener {
            val tx1 = findViewById<TextInputEditText>(R.id.tx1).toString().toInt()
            val tx2 = findViewById<TextInputEditText>(R.id.tx2).toString().toInt()

            var result = findViewById<TextView>(R.id.result)

            result.text = (tx1 + tx2).toString()
        }
```

I want to sum tx1 and tx2
but i get this message
Do not concatenate text displayed with `setText`. Use resource string with placeholders.
thanks

To find some help here!

Comment: You mean you get a warning message in your code before you run it? I see a bug that's going to make it crash. `toString()` on a TextView will give you some text like `"TextView(id = 14332342)"` so then calling `toInt()` on it will fail. You need to use `text.toString().toInt()` so you're using `toString()` on the *contents* of the TextView.

Comment: I tried, but it didn't work

Answer (score 0):

Get text of EditText before converting it to `toString()`

```
 val btnAdd = findViewById<Button>(R.id.btnAdd)
        val btnSub = findViewById<Button>(R.id.btnSub)
        btnAdd.setOnClickListener {
            val tx1 = findViewById<TextInputEditText>(R.id.tx1).text.toString().trim().toInt()
            val tx2 = findViewById<TextInputEditText>(R.id.tx2).text.toString().trim().toInt()

            var result = findViewById<TextView>(R.id.result)

            result.text = (tx1 + tx2).toString()
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Please, to retrieve the value inside an EditText you need to get the text

```
findViewById<TextInputEditText>(R.id.tx1).text.toString().toInt()
```

Second, to resolve the warning just use a String res like this:

```
<string name="my_string_res">My String with placeholder %d</string>
```

and use it in this way:

```
val sum = tx1 + tx2
result.text = getString(R.string. my_string_res, sum)
```

Comment: The first point is OK. but i didn't understand the 2nd one.

Comment: Is the solution in order to don't see the warning android studio is displaying Do not concatenate text displayed with setText. Use resource string with placeholders.